# Manager said, "K fold validation won’t fix the test-train split issue. It is just for post-validation. Kindly read about correct splitting."

Tags: python, classification, data-analysis, logistic-regression, k-fold

Initial 'Logistic Regression_Iris_Hyperparameter Tuning' that is done in the code below because Logistic regression on Iris Data set was giving me the  `Accuracy score = 1` which is wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"
data = pd.read_csv(url, names=["sepal_length", "sepal_width", "petal_length", "petal_width", "species"])

X, y = data.drop("species", 1), data.species
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

def evaluate_model(model):
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    print("Classification Report:\n", classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
    print("Confusion Matrix:\n", confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))

logreg = LogisticRegression()
evaluate_model(logreg)

param_grid = {'penalty': ['l1', 'l2'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'solver': ['newton-cg', 'lbfgs', 'liblinear', 'sag', 'saga'], 'max_iter': [100, 200, 500, 1000], 'class_weight': ['balanced']}
best_params = GridSearchCV(LogisticRegression(), param_grid, cv=10).fit(X_train, y_train).best_params_
best_logreg = LogisticRegression(**best_params)
evaluate_model(best_logreg)

data['predicted_species'] = best_logreg.predict(X)
species_ranges = data.groupby("predicted_species")[["petal_length", "petal_width"]].mean()
for index, row in species_ranges.iterrows():
    print(f"Predicted Species: {index}\nPredicted Petal length: {row['petal_length']}\nPredicted Petal width: {row['petal_width']}\n")

species_colors = {"Iris-setosa": "blue", "Iris-versicolor": "green", "Iris-virginica": "red"}
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.scatterplot(x="petal_length", y="petal_width", hue="predicted_species", data=data, palette=species_colors, legend="full").set(xlabel="Petal Length", ylabel="Petal Width", title="Scatter Plot of Iris Data Points (Best Model)")
scatter = plt.gca()
[ t.set_text(l) for t, l in zip(scatter.legend_.texts, ["Setosa", "Versicolor", "Virginica"])]
plt.show()
```

[image: Scatter plot]

I tried K-fold cross-validation to check which classification would be best fit for the Iris dataset. Below is the code for that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_val_score, KFold
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

# Load the Iris dataset
iris = load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# Split the data into training and test sets with stratified sampling
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y)

# Scale the features
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test)

# Define the classifiers to use for evaluation
classifiers = {
    'Logistic Regression': LogisticRegression(max_iter=1000),
    'Support Vector Machine': SVC(),
    'Decision Tree': DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    'Random Forest': RandomForestClassifier(),
    'K-Nearest Neighbors': KNeighborsClassifier(),
    'Naive Bayes': GaussianNB(),
    'Gradient Boosting': GradientBoostingClassifier()
}

score_names = ['accuracy', 'precision_weighted', 'recall_weighted', 'f1_weighted']

def evaluate_model(clf_name, clf):
    train_scores = [cross_val_score(clf, X_train_scaled, y_train, cv=KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=42), scoring=score).mean() for score in score_names]
    clf.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train)
    test_scores = [accuracy_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test_scaled)),
                   precision_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test_scaled), average='weighted'),
                   recall_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test_scaled), average='weighted'),
                   f1_score(y_test, clf.predict(X_test_scaled), average='weighted')]
    return train_scores, test_scores

train_scores = []
test_scores = []

for clf_name, clf in classifiers.items():
    train_score, test_score = evaluate_model(clf_name, clf)
    train_scores.append(train_score)
    test_scores.append(test_score)

train_scores = np.array(train_scores)
test_scores = np.array(test_scores)

x_values = np.arange(len(classifiers))
score_labels = ['Accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall', 'F1 Score']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, figsize=(12, 16))

for ax, score_type in zip(axes, range(4)):
    ax.plot(x_values, train_scores[:, score_type], marker='o', label='Train')
    ax.plot(x_values, test_scores[:, score_type], marker='o', linestyle='dashed', label='Test')
    ax.set_ylabel(score_labels[score_type])
    ax.set_title(f'{score_labels[score_type]} Performance of Classifiers on Iris Dataset')
    ax.set_xticks(x_values)
    ax.set_xticklabels(classifiers.keys(), rotation=45, ha='right')
    ax.legend()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: Train plot]
[image: Test plot]

Where am I wrong and how should I fix this? I have been trying to fix this issue for so long. What should I do? The manager is not helping.**

P.S: I have tried to shorten the code as much as possible which might've made some output different, but my overall issue is the same.

Comment: Please have a read on [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you give more detail on what your question is? The title suggests a) some kind of issue with your manager b) an issue with test-train split. Your first sentence just mentions that you get an incorrect accuracy of 1, Then you mention that you tried k-fold cross validation, but don't describe any issue with that. Then you ask `Where am I wrong`? So what is your question here?

Comment: Do you want to aks if k-fold cross validation is applied correctly, or want to ask about your accuracy assesement or splitting of your data in general?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear, I meant to ask that what my manager said, is that true? Am I actually making a mistake? if I am making a mistake, how do I fix it and where am I making a mistake?